# Write params require function for nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to create a simple file sharing application using Ruby on Rails. The following is my controller:

```
  1 class AttachmentsController < ApplicationController
  2   def new
  3   end
  4
  5   def create
  6     @attachment = Attachment.new(attachment_params)
  7     @attachment.save
  8     redirect_to @attachment
  9   end
 10
 11   def show
 12     @attachment = Attachment.find(params[:attachment]['file'].original_filename)
 13   end
 14
 15   private
 16   def attachment_params
 17     params.require()
 18   end
 19 end
```

The file I upload contains params in the following format:

> {
>       "utf8" => "✓",
>       "authenticity_token" => "EPd9Ed7C/qBsKu4R+t3q1Xm8aYSH7M6ZcvbpjHiJ9BnZlX0ldVCIc5AP1zcKaUB4Y7MzY8aLJI+gcPekE/hn6Q==",
>       "attachment" => {
>           "file" => # < ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile: 0x007f8612bab4f0@ tempfile = # < Tempfile: /var/folders / ft / 6
>   m5lh5sd2bb3dwj8pczwdjtm0000gn / T / RackMultipart20150622 - 5173 - 1
>   dfsg86.jpg > , @original_filename = "Kesari_bhath.jpg", @content_type
>   = "image/jpeg", @headers = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachment[file]\";
>   filename=\"Kesari_bhath.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n" >
>       },
>       "commit" => "Save Attachment" }

So I can access the `@original_filname` as `params[:attachment]['file'].original_filename`

How do write this nested attribute in the `params.require` (line 17)?

Note that the hash is `'file'` and not `file` (mind the quotes). I cannot access it with `permit.require(:attachment).permit(:file)` or `permit.require(:attachment).permit('file')` both of which cause `unknown attribute 'file' for Attachment` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`params.require(:attachment).permit(params['file'])` 


Allowed me to obtain values in the hash with `file` as key.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can try this:

```
def attachment_params
  params.require(:attachment).permit(:file)
end
```

Comment: It says `unknown attribute 'file' for Attachment`. Am I overlooking something? Does it have something to do with the fact that `file` is not a symbol here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
params.require(:attachment).permit(... , :file_attributes: [:original_filename])
```